# GET request to REST API in CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: r, crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am attempting to use "R" to pull an entity table from our CRM Microsft Dynamcis 365 using the REST API and a GET request from the "httr" package.

When I enter the endpoint url directly into the browser, I am prompted to enter my CRM credentials (username and password) and I can view the succesful response in the browser.

When I try to perform a GET request in "R" I am doing the following:

```
username <- <my CRM username>
password <- <my CRM password>
endpoint_url <- "https://<organization name>/XXX/api/data/v8.2/<endpoint>"

GET(endpoint_url, authenticate(username,password,type = "basic"))
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied

Can someone please assist?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think basic authentication works for the Web API, you need to use OAuth.

[Authenticate to Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement with the Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/authenticate-web-api)

> When you use the Web API for Customer Engagement or an on-premises
>   Internet-facing deployment (IFD) you must use OAuth as described in
>   Use OAuth to connect to Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement for apps
>   web Services.
>
> If you’re creating a single page application (SPA) using JavaScript
>   you can use the adal.js library as described in Use OAuth with
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing to connect a Single Page Application to
>   Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement.

Comment: Thanks for this info James. I am not too familiar with Oauth but I did find an "R" package that facilities this type of authorization called "ROauth". However, it asks for a consumer key and and consumer secret key. I have seen this in other Oauth packages and I was wondering if you knew what this might be?

Comment: @SteveM, it's all in the documentation; just need to work throughh them from the link in my answer, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory